# Google Apps Script - Getting permissions error in google sheets from custom menu item

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've created a google script to export specific data from a Google Sheet. Knowing that my script cannot create new files unless run from a custom menu, I created the following code:

```
function onOpen () {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [];
    MenuEntries.push({name:"Export Project sheets", 
    functionName:"exportProjectSheet"})
    ss.addMenu("Export", menuEntries);
}
```

Which in turn calls this custom function (edited most of it out except for this selection for relevancy and privacy reasons):

```
 function exportProjectSheets() {
      var id = DocumentApp.create("WO #" + projectWorkOrderNumber.getValue() 
      + " " + projectName.getValue()).getId(); //Create a new document with 
      the project name, plus grab it's id as a value
      //DOCUMENT FILLING
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id); //create a variable that refers to 
      the document body so we can edit it
 }
```

I'm pretty sure I've granted all the requisite access permissions - yet for some reason whenever I attempt to run the function in the custom menu, I get the error: "You do not have permission to call create." What gives?

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
   "dependencies": {
   },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [{
      "menuName": "exportProjectSheet",
      "functionName": "exportProjectSheet"
    }, {
      "menuName": "timestamp",
      "functionName": "timestamp"
    }, {
      "menuName": "onOpen",
      "functionName": "onOpen"
    }, {
      "menuName": "export",
      "functionName": "export"
    }]
}
```

EDIT: Added manifest file data upon request.

Comment: Share the scopes in the manifest file.

Comment: Added the manifest file. I don't see any scopes, though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot they only are there if you manually specify them. Check  `File->Project Properties-> Scopes` for auto-generated scopes. If you see `currentonly` then you have `// @OnlyCurrentDoc` specified somewhere, and won't be able to access any other files except the one this script is bound to. If you can't remove that comment, you can add `// @NotOnlyCurrentDoc` to invalidate it (i.e. if it's in a library).

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check File->Project Properties-> Scopes for auto-generated scopes. If you see currentonly then you have // @OnlyCurrentDoc specified somewhere, and won't be able to access any other files except the one this script is bound to. If you can't remove that comment, you can add // @NotOnlyCurrentDoc to invalidate it (i.e. if it's in a library).
>   -Tehhowch

This was the correct answer.